# When to use the TV-Shows Tag, a learning guide

Tags: discussion, tags

When should I use the [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) tag?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) tag should only be used when referring to the creation or editing of **tv-shows in a general sense** and should **not** be used when talking about a specific show.

For example:

If your question is **Why are there credits at the end of TV shows even though only Unicorns read them?**

- This question is about TV-Shows in a general sense, go ahead and use the [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) tag.

---

**But** if your question is **Why did Dexter shoot the pony instead of stab the unicorn?**

- This question is about a specific show: *Dexter* which *is* a TV show, but does not apply to ALL TV Shows, tag it with [dexter](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dexter)