# Join [tv-shows] and [tv-series]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I'll make this one short. We have two tags [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows) and [tv-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series).

As Tyler Shads pointed out in his [meta post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/496/when-to-use-the-tv-shows-tag-a-learning-guide) there are valid uses for [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows).

However I don't think we need to distinguish between tv-show and tv-series in that case, mostly because there are not that many questions regarding tv-shows that are not series and still fit into the scope of this site.

I suggest that they should both be joined under the main name: [tv-shows](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-shows)

Answer (score 3):

Because [tv-series](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series) doesn't have anything tagged under it, the system will auto-delete soon.  If this happens in the future, I will synonym them.